# Ошибка partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, исключения, opencv

вот код:

```
import mediapipe as mp
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
with mp_hands.Hands(
model_complexity=0,
min_detection_confidence=0.5,
min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as hands:
while cap.isOpened():
success, image = cap.read()
if not success:
    print("Ignoring empty camera frame.")
    continue
image.flags.writeable = False
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
results = hands.process(image)

image.flags.writeable = True
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
    for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
        image,
        hand_landmarks,
        mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
        mp_drawing_styles.get_default_hand_landmarks_style(),
        mp_drawing_styles.get_default_hand_connections_style())
cv2.imshow('MediaPipe Hands', cv2.flip(image, 1))
if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
    break
cap.release()
```

Ошибку вызывает вторая строка с импортом cv2.
Это весь текст ошибки:

```
    cv.gapi.wip.GStreamerPipeline = cv.gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline
    AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 
    'gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Как файл Ваш называется?

Comment: он называется Camera.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я исправляю такую ​​проблему, используя следующие команды.

```
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python

pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Answer (score 0):

Такая ошибка `AttributeError: partially initialized module 'cv2' has no attribute 'gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline' (most likely due to a circular import)` бывает, если в одной и той же папке рядом с запускаемой вами программой есть файл с именем `cv2.py`, в котором нет `gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline`, решением будет переименовать этот файл, чтобы его имя не совпадало с именем импортируемого модуля.